# OpenCV changes image when loading. Why?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I found many thread here about opencv.imread problems but not like mine. Here is the original picture and then the picture when i do :

```
plt.imshow(cv.imread('test/020.bmp', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

I suppose colors change because the original picture is in RGB and the final picture is BGR (right ?)

But i don't understand why the 't' of the word 'lighting' (top right text) is different ? I didnt find any explanation. And I think the low quality of the output image explains why i can't apply my OCR algorithm to correctly read the text.

NB : Same problem with matplotlib.image (== mpimg)

```
plt.imshow(mpimg.imread('test/020.png'))
```

[image: original image]

[image: cv.imread('test/020.bmp',1)]

Comment: You got it right, OpenCV uses BGR, matplotlib expects RGB. The issue with `t` is due to the image being scaled down to fit the plot. The data itself is quite likely fine (don't see a reason why it wouldn't)..

Comment: Ok i am stupid... It was so obvious...

And do you have any idea of tips to correctly extract the text of this image ? I don't understand why it's not easy to read the right column with a standard opencv code.

Comment: Reading white text isn't harder when you open the file with a different color model, as white is still white, only the color of the background changes

Comment: isn't it true that generic OCR works better for black texts over with background?